# Flask: Sending File Between Two Servers Results in Empty `request.files` on Receiver Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, server, client

I am attempting to send a file from one Flask server (`Server 1`) to another Flask server (`Server 2`) and then back again. However, when the file reaches `Server 2`, the `request.files` object appears to be empty, resulting in a KeyError when attempting to access it.

Here is the basic setup of my servers:

Server 1:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    file = request.files['file'].read()
    print(file)
    
    response = requests.post(url="http://127.0.0.1:5002/test",
                             headers=request.headers,
                             files={'file': file}
                             )
    
    return response.json(), response.status_code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

Server 2:

```py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=["POST"])
def test():
    file = request.files['file']  # <-- KeyError occurs here
    print(file)
    
    return 1, 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5002, debug=True)
```

This is the error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Mar/2024 10:09:02] "POST /test HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gratu\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1488, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\gratu\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1466, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\gratu\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\gratu\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\gratu\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\gratu\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "C:\Users\gratu\Projects\flasktest\app2.py", line 10, in test
    file = request.files['file']
  File "C:\Users\gratu\anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures\structures.py", line 192, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'file'
```

When a file is sent from `Server 1` to `Server 2`, the `request.files` object on `Server 2` appears to be empty, causing a KeyError. I've confirmed that the file is being sent correctly from `Server 1` as I can see the request.files dictionary with the files I have sent it when I print it.

I'm unsure why the `request.files` object is empty on `Server 2`. Is there something I'm missing in my setup or code? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In your server 1 code you are passing a string containing the file contents to the requests.post method rather than the file like object it is expecting. See https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was passing on the header. When I removed the header, it started working properly.

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    file = request.files['file'].read()
    print(file)
    
    response = requests.post(url="http://127.0.0.1:5002/test",

                             files={'file': file}
                             )
    
    return response.json(), response.status_code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```